# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Laravel

Tags: laravel

My edit.blade.php is not able to load the css/js files for some reason. I copied the code from my create.blade.php which is able to load all these css/js files. Is there a reason for this occurrence which relates to edit?

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('Post.edit');
    }
```

Comment: CSS/JS not loading mean may be you doesnot extends your default layout.. can you show your create.blade.php file and also create()..

Answer (score 0):

Please check:

- CSS files  shuld  be (if you don't use gulp etc)  on  **public/css**  folder
- You need  to load css with asset  (asset gives you path for  public folder)

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">`